# Upgrade from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.3 with Magento 1.9.4.x / PHP fatal error : Cannot use string offset as an array StocksController.php on line 152

Tags: arrays, string, magento, php-7.2, php-7.3

I changed PHP version PHP5.6 to PHP 7.3 After change, my stock extension not working properly.

**PHP fatal error : Cannot use string offset as an array StocksController.php on line 152**

What is your advice? Exactly what should I do.
**Thank you for your help**

```
 foreach ($actions as $product_id => $warehouses) {
                $update = 0;
                $is_in_stock = false;
                foreach ($warehouses as $wh_id => $qty) {
    
                    $stock = Mage::getModel('advancedinventory/stock')->getStockByProductIdAndPlaceId($product_id, $wh_id);
                    if (!$stock->getManage_stock() || $stock->getBackorder_allowed() > 0 || ($stock->getUse_config_setting_for_backorders() && Mage::getStoreConfig("cataloginventory/item_options/backorders"))) {
                        $is_in_stock = true;
                    }
                    if ($stock->getManageStock()) {
                        c = $stock->getQuantityInStock();
                      
                      $data = array(
                            "id" => $stock->getId(),
                            "quantity_in_stock" => $qty_origin + $qty
                        );
                        if (!isset($data_from[$product_id][$wh_id])) {
/* LINE 152 */         **$data_from[$product_id][$wh_id] = 0;**      
                        }
                        $update -= $data_to[$product_id][$wh_id] - $data_from[$product_id][$wh_id];
                        if ($data_to[$product_id][$wh_id] != $data_from[$product_id][$wh_id]) {
                            Mage::helper('advancedinventory/log')->insertRow("Order grid", "Assignation updated", "O#$order_id,P#$product_id,W#$wh_id ", "Assigned qty : " . $data_from[$product_id][$wh_id] . " -> " . $data_to[$product_id][$wh_id]);
                            Mage::helper('advancedinventory/log')->insertRow("Order grid", "Qty updated", "P#$product_id,W#$wh_id ", "Qty : $qty_origin -> " . ($qty_origin + $qty));
                            $stock->setData($data)->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can reference a single character in a string using an array like syntax. for example, this code prints out the letter `o` since `o` is at the fouth index position in `hello` (counting from 0)

```
$test = 'hello';
echo $test[4];
// o
```

In your program you have

```
$data_from[$product_id][$wh_id]
```

There's not enough information in your post to say for sure what's going on, but it seems like in your new version (running PHP 7.3) of the system the `$data_from` variable is being populated with a string, where in the old version (running PHP 5.6) `$data_from` was an array.

Figure out why `$data_from` has a string instead of an array (or, perhaps, if the guard clause `(!isset($data_from[$product_id][$wh_id]))` behaves differently in PHP versions) and you'll have your answer.